# Retrive the not found URL after IOerror Event

Tags: actionscript-3

I've this code:

```
var myloader:Loader=new Loader; myloader.load(new URLRequest(myXML.IMAGE[i])) 
myloader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, imgdontexist);
myloader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processloader)
```

Once the `imgdontexist` function is called, how can I retrieve ONLY the URL that hasn't been found? I have to write only the URL into a text area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private function imgdontexist(event : IOErrorEvent) : void
{
    var url:String=event.text.match(/URL: (.+)/)[1]; //your url
}
```

Comment: work
where i can find information about all syntax for text.match?
i don't know what mean (.+)/)[1]

Comment: Please, accept the answer if it helped you. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#match() Also read about regular expressions.